# Combining Matrices in Numpy to preserve outer dimension

Tags: numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray

Let's say I have this numpy array - `[[1,2],[3,4]]`. How could I stack it together K times such to preserve the dimensions of the inner matrices?

```py
[[[1,2],[3,4]], 

[[1,2],[3,4]], 

[[1,2],[3,4]]]....
```

Comment: `np.stack([a]*10)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built in function for it.

```
np.repeat([a],K,axis=0)
```

output:

```
[[[1 2]
  [3 4]]

 [[1 2]
  [3 4]]
 ...

 [[1 2]
  [3 4]]]
```